# How do I subscribe to ad-free Instagram from the web app?

Tags: instagram, instagram-account

To comply with EU GDPR and Digital Markets Act requirements, [META](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_Platforms) now offers a monthly subscription-based version of Instagram and Facebook that is ad-free. Since I'm living in a EU country, I can benefit from this.

The subscription is cheaper if purchased through the web app rather than a mobile app  because META discounts the  fees Google and Apple charges them for use of their app stores.

Effective March 2024 a subscription covers only one account and each additional linked account is subject to an additional fee.

To subscribe but avoid paying for additional accounts, I split my Instagram account off from my Facebook account.

When I try to setup a subscription in Instagram's web app (or rather the [Instagram Accounts Center](https://accountscenter.instagram.com/ad_preferences/)) I see the following message:
[image: Instagram message]

I don't understand why I'm prompted with the option to use the web app or mobile version of Facebook to manage an Instagram account that is not linked to it.

Given that it is supposed to be an available option, how do I subscribe to the no ad version of Instagram using the web app?

Comment: Updated. FWIW I also tried subscribing on Facebook, linking the accounts, and then splitting again, but the subscription always stays on the FB side (so I cancelled it again, luckily you can do that with a full refund!).

Comment: I primarily use the Android app for Instagram. But I'm not willing to give Google a share of an already overpriced service (especially when that share is coming from my wallet and not Meta's) - that's why I want to subscribe via my desktop browser (it's account-wide). If I was mainly using a desktop browser for IG, then I'd certainly go the ad blocker extension route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they fixed it (or it just took some time since I hat very recently separated my Facebook and Instagram accounts). I was just able to subscribe for 9.99€/mon on my desktop browser.